# If radio button is checked (by default or clicked) and .active contains this text, hide button

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide the Submit button if the radio button with value containing "No, I do not" is checked and .active contains the text "Commitment Statement". Please note, this radio button is selected by default so the onclick function will not work. Also, hiding the button on load does not work because if you choose yes, you are taken to the next steps of the process which is still on the same page so this will cause the Submit button to be hidden on the next step.

Please see jsfiddle for complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/w6z6gk3b/1/

```
<span class="testSequenceMapCurrentStepItem">Commitment Statement</span>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="testFormDisplayRadioButtonList" id="PC6728_formWizard_formWizard_5aa9a035_c1e7_4738_9686_144f66cfce5d">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input type="radio" onclick=" test.FormWizard.triggerHideStepRule((($(this).is(':checked') &amp;&amp; $(this).val() === 'No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest')), 'f062efd8-a797-4a23-845d-ecec13e86709'); test.FormWizard.triggerHideStepRule((($(this).is(':checked') &amp;&amp; $(this).val() === 'No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest')), '6d436f03-3afe-4bf8-998b-979c9cd0a3fd'); test.FormWizard.triggerHideStepRule((($(this).is(':checked') &amp;&amp; $(this).val() === 'No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest')), '7085eb80-4639-4279-952e-65f8041ec5ab');" value="I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)" name="PC6728$formWizard$formWizard$5aa9a035_c1e7_4738_9686_144f66cfce5d" id="PC6728_formWizard_formWizard_5aa9a035_c1e7_4738_9686_144f66cfce5d_0"><label for="PC6728_formWizard_formWizard_5aa9a035_c1e7_4738_9686_144f66cfce5d_0">I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="radio" onclick=" test.FormWizard.triggerHideStepRule((($(this).is(':checked') &amp;&amp; $(this).val() === 'No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest')), 'f062efd8-a797-4a23-845d-ecec13e86709'); test.FormWizard.triggerHideStepRule((($(this).is(':checked') &amp;&amp; $(this).val() === 'No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest')), '6d436f03-3afe-4bf8-998b-979c9cd0a3fd'); test.FormWizard.triggerHideStepRule((($(this).is(':checked') &amp;&amp; $(this).val() === 'No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest')), '7085eb80-4639-4279-952e-65f8041ec5ab');" checked="checked" value="No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest" name="PC6728$formWizard$formWizard$5aa9a035_c1e7_4738_9686_144f66cfce5d" id="PC6728_formWizard_formWizard_5aa9a035_c1e7_4738_9686_144f66cfce5d_1"><label for="PC6728_formWizard_formWizard_5aa9a035_c1e7_4738_9686_144f66cfce5d_1">No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<input type="button" class="testSequenceMapNavigationButton testFormDisplaySequenceMapNavigationButton testSequenceMapNavigationNextButton testFormDisplaySequenceMapNavigationNextButton" id="PC6728_formWizard_formWizard_nextWizardButton" onclick="(function(btn){var bDisableMe=true;if(typeof(Page_ClientValidate)=='function'){bDisableMe=Page_ClientValidate('CustomForm');}if (bDisableMe) {__doPostBack('PC6728$formWizard$formWizard$nextWizardButton','');btn.disabled=bDisableMe;}})(this);return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;PC6728$formWizard$formWizard$nextWizardButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;CustomForm&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" value="Next" name="PC6728$formWizard$formWizard$nextWizardButton">
```

Comment: One reason developers tell other developers not to write JS and CSS inline is because it can become unreadable. Your code is a perfect example of this.

Comment: The software creates the code, I cannot edit it directly, this is how it is. Your comment is very unhelpful

Comment: wow...that is some truly bizarre html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in your HTML or your fiddle where the ".active" element is. But something like this I think will work.

```
$(function(){
    setSubmit();

    $('.testFormDisplayRadioButtonList input:radio').click(function(){
        setSubmit();
    });
});


// Create a standalone function to disable and enable the button 
// so it can be called on load and on radio button click
function setSubmit(){
    var text = $('.testFormDisplayRadioButtonList input:radio:checked').val();
    var activeText = $('.active').text();
    if(text.indexOf('No, I do not') === 0 && activeText.indexOf('Commitment Statement') > -1){
        $('input:button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }else{
        $('input:button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```